# AssertionError in multi-input image classification task in TensorFlow 2 during training

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have the following model structure built with tf.keras Functional API, where the whole idea is to input six images of various views of the same item and get single classification:

[image]

I have two output classes. I'm using softmax rather than sigmoid in the classification because I want to inspect each class separately later on and it's easier if they're distinct.

I believe my input shape should therefore be `[batch_size, 6, img_width, img_height, num_channels]`, although I'm not 100% certain. Because I'm using one-hot labels, the shape of my labels should be `[batch_size, num_classes]`, right?

However, with the input X and Y shapes:

```
Tensor("X:0", shape=(2, 6, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Y:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

TensorFlow complains `AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("dense_1/Softmax:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32)`

Tracing back this error, I can see that it starts from my training function:

```
def train_function(X, Y, model, loss, optimizer, metric):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(X, training=True) #<- where the traceback occurs
        loss_value = loss(Y, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    train_acc = metric.update_state(Y, predictions)
    return loss_value
```

This function is itself called in the training loop:

```
    for batch, (X, Y) in train_ds.enumerate():
        train_loss = train_function(X, Y, model, loss, optimizer, metric)  # do the actual training
        train_acc = metric.result().numpy()  # get the training accuracy
        batch_train_loss.append(train_loss)  # save the training loss above
        batch_train_acc.append(train_acc)  # save the training accuracy above
        metric.reset_states()  # reset the metric after every batch
```

where `train_ds` is built with `tf.data.Dataset` imported from `TFRecords`.

Do you have any suggestions what could be wrong? The only thing I can think is that the input shape isn't right, but then I don't know what shape it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer here was to give each input a name:

```
dorsal_image = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="dorsal_input")
medial_image = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="medial_input")
plantar_image = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="plantar_input")
lateral_image = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="lateral_input")
proximal_image = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="proximal_input")
distal_image = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="distal_input")
```

and in the TFRecord processing make sure that the output was a dictionary and not a list:

```
return {'dorsal_input': image_lst[0], 'medial_input': image_lst[1],
        'plantar_input': image_lst[2], 'lateral_input': image_lst[3], 
        'proximal_input': image_lst[4], 'distal_input': image_lst[5]}, label
```

This was actually solved by looking at samcaetano's answer on [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34912).